# cambiar formato fecha PHP

Tags: php, date

intento hacerlo de esta forma pero no me funciona el cambio de fecha, si alguien puede ayudarme

```
$originalDate = "19/10/2022";
$timestamp = strtotime($originalDate); 
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", $timestamp );
echo  $newDate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrías que inicializar la variable `$timestamp` como un objeto tipo `DateTime()` y posteriormente cambiarle el formato de fecha de esta forma:

```
$newDate = $timestamp->format('Y-m-d');
```

Tu código final sería así:

```
$originalDate = "19-10-2022";
$timestamp = new DateTime($originalDate);
$newDate = $timestamp->format('Y-m-d');

echo  $newDate; // 2022-10-19
```

Si quieres utilizar fechas que contengan `/`, tendrías que reemplazar los `/` por `-` ya que DateTime() solo acepta las fechas con `-`. Para este caso, se utilizaría `str_replace`:

```
str_replace('/', '-', $originalDate)
```

Y tu código resultaría así:

```
$originalDate = "19/10/2022";
$timestamp = new DateTime(str_replace('/', '-', $originalDate));
$newDate = $timestamp->format('Y-m-d');

echo  $newDate; // 2022-10-19
```

Comment: Gracias por la edición @Yussef, edité la pregunta explicando este método.

Comment: No hay de que ! Quedó perfect

Comment: muchas gracias si me funciono :)